# How to exclude sub-nodes in an AEM package using filters

Tags: aem

I am creating an AEM content package and the resulting zip has the requisite META-INF directory with the filter.xml.

The package has content which is organized like so:

```
/jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/components
/jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/i18n/en_us.xml
/jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/i18n/es_mx.xml
/jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/templates
```

The filter.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/appgroup/myapp">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/appgroup/myapp/i18n(/.*)?" />
    </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Despite having the exclude pattern, the i18n node still gets deployed into the CRX when the package is installed.  Shouldn't the filter exclude the i18n node?

Ultimately, I would like to deploy just the `en_us` node and have the filters block any other languages.

My understanding is that the filter taken into consideration during install and not during compilation.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters are applied when the package is built rather than installed. With an exclusion, it shouldn't get installed by your package, but it also means if already present, it also won't get removed either! It should behave as if the package doesn't touch the area covered by the exclude filter.

**From the documentation***:

- *To include all scripts of my application but the forms component:*

  - **Root path:** `/apps/myapp`
  - **Rules:** Exclude: `/apps/myapp/components/form(/.*)?`

> The form component is not included in the package. If such a component
>   already existed when installing the package, CRX would not remove it,
>   because it is not defined by the filters.
>
> …
>
> When building the package, all the content defined by each filter is included. When extracting the package, all existing content that matches the filter is removed or replaced.

---

**Edit:** Working from a Maven bundle, you could use specify elements as excluded using a [resource](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) declaration, to avoid the content being added to the Zip e.g.:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/i18n</exclude>
                <exclude>jcr_root/apps/appgroup/myapp/i18n/**/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes> 
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

It's possible that the `filter.xml` is getting ignored by Maven on build & once the content is in the package, it's getting installed by CQ regardless.

---

**EDIT2:** * Initial example is no longer *in* the documentation now that Day.com is down, but should still hold true. Updated documentation is [now available here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/package-manager.html#PackageFilters)

Comment: I am not generating the zip through AEM.  I am using Maven.  The zip has the i18n node and sub nodes in it, and the filter.xml excludes them as indicated.  The i18n node doesn't already exist in the CRX. On install, AEM doesn't respect the filter creates the i18n node.  Are you saying that the filter would prevent an override if the i18n node was already there, but since the node isn't there, AEM creates it?

Comment: You may need to exclude them when building your package — Maven will ignore your `filter.xml` as it means nothing to it; I'm not sure then what CQ will do if the content is in the package but not in the filter  - by your experience it sounds like it installs it anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood how AEM interprets the exclude filter on install. If the node is in the package zip but not in the CRX, then AEM creates it.  However, if the excluded node is in the CRX already, then AEM will not override it. I am guessing this is based on the default filter `mode` which is `merge`, I thought but this blog says `replace` (see http://www.wemblog.com/2012/04/how-to-change-package-install-behavior.html ) Anyway, thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: After more testing, the default filter mode does seem to be `replace`. (`<filter root="/apps/myapp" mode="replace" />`)

Comment: @anotherdave if I mentioned root path /apps/myapp and excludes /apps/myapp/components/form(/.*)? then it does not exclude. Are you sure it works correctly?